# Javascript Background Table

Tags: javascript, background

im trying to set background color of fields with td id = "red" but It set only the first, whats the problem?I think that I will have to set diferent names maybe?

Here is my code:

```
<table id="theTable"> 

  <tr>

    <td id= "red">0 - some txt</td> 

    <td>1 - some txt</td>

    <td>2 - some txt</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td id = "red">3 - some txt</td>

    <td>4 - some txt</td>

    <td>5 - some txt</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td><button type="button" onclick="funcion('red')">Try it</button></td>


  </tr>

</table>

<script>

function funcion (id) {

  document.getElementById('red').style.backgroundColor = "red";

}


</script>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ids need to be unique document-wide. `getElementById` is supposed to return only one element.

Comment: you need to use classes instead of IDs for such a job.

Comment: Ever wonder why they called it `getElementById` and not `getElementsById`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since IDs **must be unique** you should use classes and this JavaScript:

```
function funcion(id) {
    var tds = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fMBgz/)**

HTML

```
<table id="theTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="red">0 - some txt</td>
        <td>1 - some txt</td>
        <td>2 - some txt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">3 - some txt</td>
        <td>4 - some txt</td>
        <td>5 - some txt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" onclick="funcion('red')">Try it</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: oh well, just did it a couple of seconds after you there: http://jsfiddle.net/KMMFM/ :P well done!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using classes, as ID's are meant to be unique, thus the function only returns the first occurrence.

The code would look something like this:

```
<table id="theTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="red">some text</td>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">some text</td>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">some text</td>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the function:

```
function makeThemRed()
{
    var redElements = document.getElementsByClassName("red");

    for(var i = 0; i < redElements.length; i++)
    { 
        redElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

because you need to iterate through the results, which is best done by a for loop.